# Why am I not getting slayer points for completing tasks?

Tags: runescape

I have completed about 5 task for Vannaka but when I look in my currency pouch it still says that I have 0 slayer points. I was looking online and I could find no other requirements. Is there something else I need to do before I can start accumulating slayer points? Or some place I need to go to get them?

Comment: You stated that you got your tasks from Vannaka, but it should also be noted that doing tasks for Turael does not give you points and instead resets the task count to zero (which means you need to do 5 more tasks to start accumulating points).  Also, in OSRS, [Krystilia](https://oldschoolrunescape.wikia.com/wiki/Krystilia)'s tasks have a separate counter and also require 5 tasks before points begin to accumulate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [RuneScape Wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Slayer_points), "A minimum of five tasks must be completed before points are awarded". You should receive 2 slayer points upon completion of your next task from Vannaka (or 4 if you have completed the quest "Smoking Kills")

Comment: Just as a side note, the wiki also states the list shows the maximum amount of slayer points obtainable. If the OP has not completed the quest "Smoking Kills", they will receive 2 slayer points from Vannaka instead of 4

Comment: @Wondercricket ah, I didn't see that. Updated.